# Focus TextInput after select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I got an error when I tried to focus a TextInput after selecting a Dropdown value.
And also, when I tried to write, it's lost focus, but I think it is related to how I'm trying to do this.

This is the function that I use to set the inputRef

```
  let inputRef = useRef<TextInput | null>(null)

  const onSelectFormat = (format) => {
    setDropdownListVisibility('')
    setInputFocused(true)
    inputRef.current &&  inputRef.current.focus()
  }
```

The CustomInput Component that I send the inputRef variable

```
      <CustomInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={onChangeInputText}
        isFocused={isInputFocused}
        onFocus={() => setInputFocused(true)}
        getRef={ref => (inputRef = { current: ref })}
      />
```

And finally, this is the child component that I pass the ref.

```
        <TextInput
          ref={getRef}
          value={value}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          style={styles.input}
          onFocus={onFocus}
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code appears to be partially set up for [call-back refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), and partially for regular refs, (created with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) or [`createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs)).
If you create the ref with `useRef`, just can just pass it all the way down to the element where it is used, without using any functions or assignments (and it can also be a constant).

The code should work if you replace `getRef={ref => (inputRef = { current: ref })}` in the `CustomInput` element with `getRef={inputRef}`, but it will be cleaner if you also use the prop name `inputRef` instead of `getRef`:

```
..
const inputRef = useRef<TextInput | null>(null)

const onSelectFormat = (format) => {
  setDropdownListVisibility('')
  setInputFocused(true)
  inputRef.current?.focus()
}
..
```

```
  ..
  <CustomInput
    value={value}
    onChangeText={onChangeInputText}
    isFocused={isInputFocused}
    onFocus={() => setInputFocused(true)}
    inputRef={inputRef}
  />
  ..
```

```
  ..
  <TextInput
    ref={inputRef}
    value={value}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    style={styles.input}
    onFocus={onFocus}
  />
  ..
```

(with the function definition for `CustomInput` also adapted to the new `inputRef` prop name)